# Posting image to Facebook using SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I have an app where I save the current view as an image using the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
savedImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now I want to be able to post this image to Facebook. I have the following code:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        slComposeView = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [slComposeView addImage: [UIImage imageNamed:savedImg]];
        [self presentViewController:slComposeView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Obviously this is wrong because I cannot pass UIImage to an NSString. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the imageNamed call and pass the savedImg variable directly into the addImage call.

Comment: I thought of everything else except that.. Silly me. But thanks a lot!!